# Exporting on radgrid works for aspx page but not for ascx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

In telerik rad grid exporting for grid works for aspx page but for ascx page the "page bar" does not display and it also shows all the grid records.
I have also added the following code in the itemdatabound event of radgrid

```
 if (e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToPdfCommandName || e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToWordCommandName
                 || e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToExcelCommandName || e.CommandName == Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.ExportToCsvCommandName)
            {
                ConfigureExport(grdQuestionSet);
            }
```

And this is my configure export method

```
  public void ConfigureExport(WclGrid sysXConfigureExport)
    {
        try
        {
            sysXConfigureExport.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
            sysXConfigureExport.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
            sysXConfigureExport.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
            sysXConfigureExport.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = false;
            sysXConfigureExport.MasterTableView.ClearChildEditItems();
            sysXConfigureExport.MasterTableView.AllowFilteringByColumn = false; // Added to Remove Blank row in case of Export
        }
        catch (SysXException ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats `ConfigureExport` method containing...Are you getting any exceptions too for it...??

Comment: make sure AJAX is not involved in the UC setup. Export cannot work with AJAX.

Comment: ajax is not involved there...